# Teradata - Cannot nest aggregate operations

Tags: teradata

The PROD_AMT I'd like to get is when ACCT_NBR, PROD_NBR And PROD_AMT are the same, I only need one PROD_AMT which is 100 (from distinct), and when ACCT_NBR are the same but PROD_NBR are different, then the PROD_AMT I need is 90 (30+60)

```
SELECT ACCT_NBR
,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN PROD_NBR = 1 THEN SUM(DISTINCT PROD_AMT)
                     WHEN PROD_NBR > 1 THEN SUM(PROD_AMT)
                END) AS AMT
FROM TABLE

ACCT_NBR PROD_NBR PROD_AMT
3007     001      30
3007     002      60
1000     003      100
1000     003      100
```

Comment: Is it that you want to SUM the `amt` in the event that there is a `prod_nbr` of 1 for the `acct_nbr`, and you want to get the distinct `prod_amt` in the event that the `acct_nbr` does not contain a record with the `prod_nbr`. As written, it's not terribly clear what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a few ways to solve this. Using a subquery to determine which records should be summed vs which ones should be distinct, you could use:

```
SELECT
    acct_nbr,
    CASE WHEN sumflag = 'X' THEN SUM(prod_amt) ELSE MAX(prod_amt) END as amt
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            acct_nbr,
            prod_nbr,
            prod_amt,
            CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Acct_nbr, prod_nbr, prod_amt) = 1 THEN 'X' ELSE NULL END AS sumflag
        FROM
            table
    )t1
GROUP BY acct_nbr, sumflag
```

I'm just using `MAX()` here since it doesn't matter... all the values that will be aggregated with `max()` we know are duplicates, so it's a wash.

You could get similar results with a UNION query where one query would do the summing in the event that the records are distinct, and the other would just return distinct prod_amt's where the records are duplicates.

While the above example is nice if you truly have different aggregation needs depending on complex logic, for your question there's a simpler way of doing the same thing that doesn't use window functions:

```
SELECT  
    acct_nbr,
    sum(prod_amt) AS amt
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            acct_nbr,   
            prod_amt
        FROM 
            table
    )t1
GROUP BY 1
```

If you need to adapt this to a complex statement you could just sling your complex statement in as subquery where `table` is above like:

```
SELECT  
    acct_nbr,
    sum(prod_amt) AS amt
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            acct_nbr,   
            prod_amt
        FROM 
            (
                YOUR REALLY COMPLEX QUERY GOES IN HERE
            )t2

    )t1
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Is sumflag a column?  I don't have this column in my table.

Comment: It is a derived column that is calculated using the Window Formula `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Acct_nbr, prod_nbr, prod_amt)` which will group the records together by `acct_nbr`, `prod_nbr`, and `prod_amt` and count how many it finds... then look for groups that have only a single record. If it is a group with a single record then it gets an 'X'

Comment: I can't get this to work correctly because my real query has some left join with other tables.   Is there a way I could use CASE only in the select to get both prod_amt 100 and 90 that I need?

Comment: I just added a more simple way to get your results. It still requires a subquery, but I've added an example where you can slide in your existing SQL statement to make it easier to implement. I don't think you'll be able to get around using a subquery to make this happen since you need to perform both a DISTINCT/GROUP BY as well as Aggregation on the same field. Furthermore, if you try to move the Window Functio up into the main query, you then have to GROUP BY all of the fields, which gets you back to square one.

Comment: I used subquery as you suggested and so it works and I got the result.  Thanks so much!